# Import appengine library in a gwt module

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, web-applications

I have a web application that contains a GWT module. In the client of my GWT module I want to use the library "com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService" but, when I compile the gwt module, I have this error: "The import com.google.appengine.api.datastore cannot be resolved". Where is the problem

Answer (score 0):

The first and most obvious things to ask are:
Have you downloaded the java appengine SDK and have you made the JAR files contained within available to your app?
Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, I am using Eclipse and I have downloaded the appengine SDK.. outside the GWT module my code work, so I believe that maybe I can't use appengine libraries in a GWT module..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible.  Anything on the client side gets translated to javascript that is ran in the browsers.  You can directly access a database through javascript in the browser.  Not all Java code can run in a browser.  In fact not even all the JRE classes can be used either.  If you need a type of storage on the client side, look at html 5 local storage.